# Problema al pasar variables como parámetro

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un código con unas variables globales que son usadas por unas funciones definidas en la cabecera. Me gustaría separar las funciones y el main poniéndolos en dos archivos diferentes.
El problema está en que al intentar pasar estas variables desde el main a una de las funciones, me da problemas.

El código original es éste:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#  == METHOD 2 ==
# Basic usage of optimize.leastsq
from scipy import optimize as opt
import numpy as np
import f02_graphs as grp

#method_2  = "leastsq"

def calc_R(xc, yc):
    """ Calculate the distance of each 2D points from the center (xc, yc) """
    return np.sqrt((x-xc)**2 + (y-yc)**2)


def f_2(c):
    """ Calculate the algebraic distance between the 2D points and the mean circle centered at c=(xc, yc) """
    Ri = calc_R(*c)
    return Ri - Ri.mean()

# Datos.  
x = [36, 36, 19, 18, 33, 26]
y = [14, 10, 28, 31, 18, 26]
basename = 'arc'

# Coordenadas del baricentro.
x_m = np.mean(x)
y_m = np.mean(y)
barycenter = x_m, y_m
# Aplicamos un algoritmo para aproximar el centro de la circunferencia.
circle_center, ier = opt.leastsq(f_2, barycenter)
xc, yc = circle_center

# Calculamos la distancia al centro de cada par x,y.
R_xy = calc_R(xc, yc)
# Calculamos el promedio de todoas las distancias de R_xy.
R_2 = R_xy.mean()
```

Mi versión en la que he separado el código en dos archivos es la siguiente:

> main

```
from scipy import optimize as opt
import numpy as np
import f02_graphs as grp
import f08_adjustments as adj

x = [36, 36, 19, 18, 33, 26]
y = [14, 10, 28, 31, 18, 26]
basename = 'arc'



# Coordenadas del baricentro.
x_m = np.mean(x)
y_m = np.mean(y)
barycenter = x_m, y_m
# Aplicamos un algoritmo para aproximar el centro de la circunferencia.
circle_center, ier = opt.leastsq(adj.f_2, barycenter)
xc, yc = circle_center

# Calculamos la distancia al centro de cada par x,y.
R_xy = adj.calc_R(x, y, xc, yc)
# Calculamos el promedio de todoas las distancias de R_xy.
R_2 = R_xy.mean()
```

> funciones

```
import numpy as np

def calc_R(x, y, xc, yc):

    radius = np.sqrt((x - xc)**2 + (y - yc)**2)

    return radius


def f_2(c):

    Ri = calc_R(*c)
    dist = Ri - Ri.mean()

    return dist
```

Entiendo que la función `f_2` ha de pasar los valores `x, y` como parámetro, pero no sé cómo hacerlo porque en realidad es `opt.leastsq` quien llama a `f_2`.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Comment: He buscado cómo funciona `leastsq` y se escapa por completo a mis conocimientos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Planteamiento inicial, explicación

La función `leastsq` tiene como misión encontrar cierto par, llamémosle `(xc,yc)`, que minimice el valor de de la suma de "errores" entre ese punto y otra serie de ellos, para lo cual necesita dos elementos:

- Una función que calcule una lista de "errores" entre una serie de puntos y el punto que estamos buscando `(xc, yc)` (tu código usa `f_2` como tal función)
- Un valor inicial para el punto `(xc, yc)` (y para ello le pasamos `barycenter`)

La forma en que opera `leastsq` consiste en llamar a la función que le has pasado como primer parámetro (en nuestro caso `f_2`) pasándole como parámetro el valor del punto que buscamos, inicialmente `barycenter`. Espera que la función `f_2` le retorne una lista de errores y con ella calcula la suma de los cuadrados y estima en qué dirección debe mover el punto inicial para disminuir esa suma. Vuelve a llamar a `f_2` con el nuevo valor del punto y obtiene una nueva lista de errores, y así sucesivamente, hasta que considere que ya ha encontrado el punto en que la suma de errores (cuadrática) es mínima. Eso será lo que retorne como primer resultado, que tu código guarda en `circle_center`.

Como ves, la función `f_2` es llamada múltiples veces, pero cada vez que se le llama se le pasa un solo parámetro: el punto que en ese momento se está considerando como candidato. Para calcular la lista de errores, lo que hace la función es:

```
def f_2(c):
    Ri = calc_R(*c)
    dist = Ri - Ri.mean()
    return dist
```

`c` es el punto candidato. Lo primero que hace con él es invocar `calc_R(*c)`, lo que "desempaqueta" la tupla `c` en sus dos componentes, y pasa estos dos componentes a la función `calc_R()`, la cual recibe por tanto dos parámetros: las coordenadas `x` e `y` del punto candidato.

Lo que hace `calc_R()` es calcular la distancia de ese "supuesto centro" a cada uno de los puntos que se están considerando, y retorna un vector con esas distancias. La función `f_2` entonces resta a cada una de esas distancias el promedio de ellas y retorna la lista de resultados. Esa lista serán los errores que `leastsq` tratará de minimizar, a base de ir moviendo el candidato a centro de la circunferencia en la dirección apropiada.

Ahora bien, vemos que `calc_R()` necesita conocer, además del "candidato", el resto de puntos del problema. En lugar de recibirlos como parámetro, los toma de variables globales.

### El problema

No queremos eso. Queremos pasárselos como parámetro a `calc_R()`, pero quien está llamando a `calc_R()` es `f_2()`, luego sería `f_2()` quien se los tiene que pasar. Pero para ello `f_2()` tendría que recibirlos como parámetro también y.. ¿quién está llamando a `f_2()`? Pues resulta que es `leastsq`, por lo que necesitamos alguna forma de "inyectar" esos parámetros en la llamada que `leastsq` hace a `f_2()`, pues ya hemos visto que por defecto sólo le pasará un parámetro: el "candidato a centro"

Tenemos dos posibles soluciones:

- Usar el parámetro `args` de `leastsq`
- Usar `functools.partial()`

#### Usando `args`

A través de este parámetro se le puede especificar a `leastsq` qué parámetros *adicionales* queremos que le pase a `f_2()` cuando la invoque (además del punto candidato a centro, que ese se lo pasará de todas formas). Estos parámetros extra los pasaría *después* del punto candidato.

Así pues invocaríamos `leastsq` en la forma siguiente:

```
circle_center, ier = opt.leastsq(f_2, barycenter, args=(x, y))
```

Además de esto, naturalmente, tenemos que reescribir `f_2()` para que efectivamente recoja estos parámetros y se los pase a `calc_R()`, así:

```
def f_2(c, x, y):
    """ Calculate the algebraic distance between the 2D points and the mean circle centered at c=(xc, yc) """
    Ri = calc_R(x, y, *c)
    return Ri - Ri.mean()
```

Y finalmente `calc_R()` quedaría así:

```
def calc_R(x, y, xc, yc):
    """ Calculate the distance of each 2D points from the center (xc, yc) """
    return np.sqrt((x-xc)**2 + (y-yc)**2)
```

(Observa que al ser `x` e `y` listas, se está computando en realidad una operación vectorial, que retornará otra lista)

#### Usando `functools.partial()`

Este enfoque usa programación funcional para construir una nueva función a partir de otra dada.

Supón que tenemos esta función que recibe tres parámetros (observa que en este caso los dos primeros son `x` e `y`, en lugar de ser los dos últimos):

```
def f_2(x,y,c):
    """ Calculate the algebraic distance between the 2D points and the mean circle centered at c=(xc, yc) """
    print(c)
    Ri = calc_R(x,y,*c)
    return Ri - Ri.mean()
```

Y supón también que `leastsq` no tuviera el parámetro `args`, sino que a la función a la que llama, le pasará siempre un sólo parámetro (`c`).

En este caso necesitaríamos una función que reciba un solo parámetro (`c`) pero que internamente llamara a `f_2` pasándole los tres parámetros (`x`, `y`, `c`). Esto es lo que `functools.partial` nos permite construir. La expresión siguiente:

```
import functools
f = functools.partial(f_2, x, y)
```

hace justamente eso. Crea una función `f` a la que podrías llamar así: `f(resto_de_parámetros)`  y que internamente llamará a `f_2(x,y, resto_de_parámetros)`.

Por tanto con este enfoque tendríamos:

```
# Aplicamos un algoritmo para aproximar el centro de la circunferencia.
circle_center, ier = opt.leastsq(functools.partial(f_2, x, y), barycenter)
```

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que es necesario hacer sucesivas llamadas ¿Cuál de las dos soluciones es más eficiente?

Comment: @Zhisi Posiblemente la que usa `args`, ya que la otra implica un nivel más de indirección a la hora de invocar la función (ya que, aunque la sintaxis lo haga transparente, cuando `leastsq` llame a `f_2`, en realidad estará llamando a un "envoltorio" construído por `functools.partial`, que a su vez llama a `f_2` pasándole los parámetros extra)

Answer (score 1):

Revisando la documentación de [`leastsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html) puedes ver que tiene un parámetro `args` el cual tiene la siguiente documentación:

> **args** : tuple, optional Any extra arguments to func are placed in this
>   tuple.

Es decir, cualquier parámetro adicional de la función se debería indicar por medio de una tupla en este parámetro. En tu caso debería ser algo así:

```
circle_center, ier = opt.leastsq(adj.f_2, barycenter, args=(x, y, xc, yc))
```