# ajuste circulo mínimos cuadrados

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

Tengo un conjunto de datos que he extraído de un DataFrame hecho con pandas, formado por 18383 registros (x,y,z0,z,arbol). Dichos datos se corresponden con la sección de un árbol y por eso se distribuyen en el espacio en forma de círculo. Me gustaría hacer un ajuste por mínimos cuadrados para obtener el diámetro del círculo que describen. Soy muy novata en Python y encontrado este fragmento de código que permite hacer el ajuste, sin embargo no sé cómo introducir mi DataFrame en él para hacer el ajuste, ¿debería convertirlo en una matriz?. El código es:

```
method_2 = "leastsq"
from numpy import *
from scipy import optimize

def calc_R(xc, yc):
    """ calculate the distance of each 2D points from the center (xc, yc) """
    return sqrt((x-xc)**2 + (y-yc)**2)

def f_2(c):
    """ calculate the algebraic distance between the data points and the mean circle centered at c=(xc, yc) """
    Ri = calc_R(*c)
    return Ri - Ri.mean()

center_estimate = x_m, y_m
center_2, ier = optimize.leastsq(f_2, center_estimate)

xc_2, yc_2 = center_2
Ri_2       = calc_R(*center_2)
R_2        = Ri_2.mean()
residu_2   = sum((Ri_2 - R_2)**2)
```

Adjunto una imagen del gráfico que he hecho con mis datos así como de los datos que estoy utilizando

[image]
[image]

Comment: podrias compartir el dataframe como texto, no pensaras que vamos escribir esos numeros

Comment: Perdona, todavía no manejo muy bien la página...Ahí va el enlace de los datos en formato .txt  https://www.dropbox.com/s/ut3mi8etuqmo7wh/0arbol1.7z?dl=0

Comment: entonces lee [ask] por favor y pasa el [tour]

Comment: @Covadonga El enlace que has puesto lleva a un archivo `.7z` que está vacío.

Comment: @Covadonga Por otro lado, tu pregunta se parece mucho a [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166282/problema-al-pasar-variables-como-par%C3%A1metro) que respondí hace un tiempo. Mira si te puede ser de utilidad mi respuesta.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v4k03tef8tf572q/0arbol1.txt?dl=0 Ahora lo he comprobado y ya está bien subido. Voy a mirar tu respuesta de hace un tiempo a ver si me sirve.

Comment: @Covadonga ¿Estás segura de que los datos del archivo 0arbol1.txt que has subido a Dropbox son correctos? No tienen la misma pinta que el dataframe cuya imagen has pegado. En concreto, todas las columnas tienen solamente valores enteros, y al pintar la gráfica lógicamente no sale ninguna forma circular.

Comment: Mil disculpas, intenté exportar mi Dataframe directamente desde Python a .txt y al hacerlo quité los decimales si querer. Ahora debería estar bien https://www.dropbox.com/s/mc7njkif3ql78ts/arbol1.txt?dl=0 Gracias por tu paciencia @abulafia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basándome en mi respuesta a [otra pregunta sobre ajuste de círculos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166282/problema-al-pasar-variables-como-par%C3%A1metro), la adaptación es muy sencilla.

En lugar las listas `x` e `y` que usaba el problema original para contener las coordenadas de los puntos, en esta ocasión usaremos `arbol.x` y `arbol.y`, siendo `arbol` un dataframe pandas que contiene los datos de un árbol (y que tiene al menos dos columnas llamadas `x` e `y`).

El siguiente código muestra cómo operar (he ejecutado todos los comandos mostrados en celdas de un Jupyter Notebook):

1. Bajarse los datos proporcionados por la usuaria

   ```
   !wget "https://www.dropbox.com/s/mc7njkif3ql78ts/arbol1.txt?dl=1" -o /dev/null -O arbol1.txt
   ```
2. Leerlos en un dataframe pandas y ver que tienen buen aspecto

   ```
   # Leer los datos con pandas
   import pandas as pd
   df = pd.read_table("arbol1.txt", header=0)
   df.head()
   ```

   ---

   ```
           x       y     z0       z  arbol
   0  23.215  73.319  1.210  1068.3      1
   1  23.209  73.332  1.210  1068.3      1
   2  23.203  73.344  1.209  1068.3      1
   3  23.208  73.321  1.397  1068.5      1
   4  23.207  73.321  1.369  1068.4      1
   ```
3. Quedarse con los datos del "arbol 1" y pintarlos para ver que siguen una forma más o menos circular:

   ```
   # Quedarse con un arbol, por ejemplo el 3
   arbol = df[df.arbol == 1]
   ax = arbol.plot(x="x", y="y", kind="scatter")
   ax.set_aspect('equal')
   ```

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
4. Utilizar el código de la otra pregunta, adaptado a este caso, para calcular el centro y radio del círculo:

   ```
   # Hacer el ajuste (basado en otra respuesta mía)
   # https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/166354/7123

   from scipy import optimize as opt
   import numpy as np

   def calc_R(x, y, xc, yc):
       """ Calculate the distance of each 2D points from the center (xc, yc) """
       return np.sqrt((x-xc)**2 + (y-yc)**2)

   def f_2(c, x, y):
       """ Calculate the algebraic distance between the 2D points and the mean circle centered at c=(xc, yc) """
       Ri = calc_R(x, y, *c)
       return Ri - Ri.mean()

   # Coordenadas del baricentro (estimación inicial del centro del círculo)
   x_m = arbol.x.mean()
   y_m = arbol.y.mean()
   barycenter = x_m, y_m
   # Aplicamos un algoritmo para aproximar el centro de la circunferencia.
   circle_center, ier = opt.leastsq(f_2, barycenter, args=(arbol.x, arbol.y))
   xc, yc = circle_center
   print("Centro del círculo:", xc, yc)

   # El radio encontrado
   r = calc_R(arbol.x, arbol.y, *circle_center).mean()
   print("Radio del árbol:", r)
   ```

   ---

   ```
   Centro del círculo: 22.98550108357253 73.229096837513
   Radio del árbol: 0.2332831108455863
   ```

Finalmente podemos pintar encima de la gráfica anterior el círculo que hemos encontrado. Así:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

ax = arbol.plot(x="x", y="y", kind="scatter")
ax.plot(x=xc, y=yc, mark="*", color="red")
ax.add_collection(PatchCollection([Circle((xc, yc), r)], color="orange", alpha=0.2))
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_xlim((xc-r*1.1, xc+r*1.1))
ax.set_ylim((yc-r*1.1, yc+r*1.1))
```

[image: Resultado]